# Adding a button in Toolbar in Winedt 10

Tags: winedt, tools

I am using Winedt 10 and in its Toolbar some icon is missed. For example, I would like to use "Insert Environment" directly in "Toolbar" by only clicking on its icon as it was in "Winedt 9", and I do not want every time to go to "Menu->Insert->Insert Environment" to use it.

The same question for Undo and Redo and many others as it was in Winedt 9.

Is there any way to add its icon again to Toolbar.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it :) . I did it by

"Options->Toolbar->Legacy Default"

Comment: wonder why they removed all those useful buttons.

Comment: Hidden in the 10.3 update below is the answer: the expected menu bar with useful buttons still exists as one of several pre-designed menu bars. The default menu bar is a minimal design. To replace the minimal menu bar by a richer one requires some detailed edits as outlined below in the 10.3 update.

Answer (score 1):

## Update for WinEdt 10.3 (2021)

Details will be added to Asad's correct 2017 answer. The change to another toolbar is done from **Options  ==>  Options Interface**
by a sequence of text edits in WinEdt. The steps:

**Open Toolbar.ini**

Open **Options Interface** and double-click **Menus and Toolbar** then
Double-click **Toolbar** which opens Toolbar.ini for editing.

```
This file is initially a copy of the file of the same name
located in C:/Program Files/WinEdt Team/WinEdt 10/ConfigEx/ 
That location is never edited, the edits being made to user XXXXX directory
C:\users\XXXXX\Application Data\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 10\ConfigEx\Toolbar.ini
```

**Disable Default Toolbar**

Cursor to line 106, then edit Toolbar.ini to look like:

> ```
> // Default Toolbar
> // 
> // %%INCLUDE="ConfigEx\Toolbars\Toolbar1d.ini" // 1-row Toolbar (Default)
> ```

The six alternative toolbars are on lines 127-133. The lines following an un-commented active string %%INCLUDE are not used in the toolbar.

**Enable Legacy Toolbar**

All %%INCLUDE lines in Toolbar.ini must be commented out, then lines after
line 136 (2-row Legacy Toolbar) can be edited to customize the
buttons and drop-down menus.
**Important**:  Save the file Toolbar.ini. To enable the changes, double-click on the icon far left on row 2 of the **Options Interface**.

> This action writes the file Toolbar.ini to the user directory
> and refreshes the toolbar.
> Failure to do this step will cause the toolbar to remain unchanged.
> Wizards might use a programming editor on Toolbar.ini in the
> User directory, but the steps to invoke the new toolbar must
> be completed in WinEdt as outlined above. **Never** edit
> Toolbar.ini in the **Program Files** directory - it must remain the original unchanged file.

**Editing the Legacy Toolbar**

Assumed: both steps above were completed successfully. An example: add at the end of file ToolBar.ini this button:

```
BUTTON="Wordpad"   // Location: Toolbar.ini
```

**Important**: The inserted BUTTON (or MENU) must exist as an ITEM in MainMenu.ini. For instance:

```
ITEM="Wordpad"   // Location: MainMenu.ini
```

**Editing MainMenu.ini**

Example continued. In the **Options Interface** double-click on MainMenu.ini. This opens an editor window with the same file name, but destination in the User folder. The example inserts into **MainMenu.ini** about line 3429:

```
ITEM="Wordpad"
CAPTION="Wordpad"
IMAGE="Asymptote" // Later, use wordpad.png 16x16 transparent
MACRO="Run('c:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe','%!P',0,0,'Wordpad');"
```

The image **Asymptote.png** already exists in WinEdt. To use image **wordpad.png** instead requires learning how to add images to WinEdt, another project that can consume hours.

**Important**:  Save the file MainMenu.ini. To enable the changes, double-click on the icon far left on row 2 of the **Options Interface**.